# Error installing fluidsim package due to library fftw3

Tags: libraries

I get an error every time I try to install fluidsim. It seems that it is due to the library fft3w. I checked this library, and it is well installed on the system. The error is the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3f
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3l
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3_threads
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3f_threads
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfftw3l_threads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'develop' failed
make: *** [develop] Error 1
(Env) mikel@Miguel:~/Env/fluidsim$
```

I could not figure out what is the problem. Do you have any idea what's the matter? Thank you for the help.

mikel

```
(Env) mikel@Miguel:~/Env/fluidsim$ dpkg -l|grep libfftw3
ii  libfftw3-double3:amd64                      3.3.4-2ubuntu1                                              amd64        Library for computing Fast Fourier Transforms - Double precision
ii  libfftw3-single3:amd64                      3.3.4-2ubuntu1                                              amd64        Library for computing Fast Fourier Transforms - Single precision
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg -l | grep libfftw3`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have *all* of the `libfftw3` component packages installed - perhaps because you installed `libfftw3-single3` and `libfftw3-double3` instead of the complete `libfftw3-dev` development package.

Try (re)installing `libfftw3-dev`

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libfftw3-dev
```

and if that doesn't work, try installing the sub-packages directly

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libfftw3-long3 libfftw3-single3
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the response! I had personal issues!! I tried what you told me and it worked!! Thanks for the help